# How to add a file to /etc in NixOS?

Tags: nixos

What is the NixOS-way to put a configuration file in `/etc`?

E.g. I want to drop `/etc/nanorc`. I found some forum entries talking about programming it into `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`, but could not find any documentation about that...

Answer (score 20):

To create a file in `/etc` on NixOS, use `environment.etc` in `configuration.nix`. Here's an example:

```
environment.etc = {
  # Creates /etc/nanorc
  nanorc = {
    text = ''
      whatever you want to put in the file goes here.
    '';

    # The UNIX file mode bits
    mode = "0440";
  };
};
```

Answer (score 14):

Additionally, you can also add a file from a path with:

```
environment.etc = {
  somerc.source = /etc/somerc;
};
```

Or a directory:

```
environment.etc = {
  aDir.source = ./aDir;
};
```

Or a package path:

```
environment.etc = {
  "X11/xorg.conf.d/90-super.conf".source = "${pkgs.displayfix}/share/displayfix/data/90-super.conf";
};
```

Comment: Doesn't your first example `/etc/somerc` point to itself?

Comment: I recall I was adding an etc file of my local machine to another machine with NixOps. What do you suggest? Should I just puth a `/path/to/file` instead?