# How to add an additional configuration file to an existing nix derivation?

Tags: configuration, nixos

Using the linux distribution `nixos`, I have 2 similar problems:

- I have to add my `custom_syntax_color_scheme.vim` file to the existing `/share/vim/vim80/colors` folder in the nix store from existing package `nixos.vim`
- I have to add a `custom-tex-template.tex` file to the existing `/share/ghc-8.2.2/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.2.2/pandoc-2.0.6/data/templates/` folder in the nix store from existing package `pandoc` (I suppose, otherwise it's `nixos.texlive.combined.scheme-full`)

I have skimmed through the Nix-Pills, but I cannot make my mind about solving this particular problem: adding a configuration file to an existing derivation.

What is the Nix way of doing it?

I suppose I have to create a new derivation that include the file I want, but I don't know how and how the existing package will manage to include it.

My problem feels similar to [How to add a file to /etc in NixOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/500025/4175) which now has an answer, but cannot be applied here.

Comment: What you're trying to do differs from adding a file to /etc. In short, you cannot add files to another package in the Nix store. However, generally speaking, some packages provide optional inputs you can use to configure them. Have you checked the Nixpkgs manual? I know there's a section on VIM, but I'm not sure about Tex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both case, it is not needed to alter the files installed by the package:

1. Put the custom `colorscheme` files into the folder `~/.vim/colors`. This folder needs to be created.
2. the option passed to `pandoc --template` should contain either the template file name **with the extension**, either the path to the template file name. (I was following the README file blindly, and it was giving command example with the template name without the file extension)